# Modeling the coin weighting problem

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ coins with weights $0$ or $1$ and a scale for weighting them. We would like to determine the weight of each coin by minimizing the number of weightings.

The book that I am reading states that the above problem  can be modeled in the following way. We say that the subsets $S_1,\ldots,S_m$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are *determing* if any $T \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ can be uniquely determined by the cardinalities $|S_i \cap T|$ for $1 \leq i \leq m.$ The minimum number of weightings is then equivalent to the least $m$ for which a determing sequence of sets exists.

My question is. How exactly does this reduce to the coin weighting problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the coins be $C_1,\dots,C_n$. Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the set of coins of weight $1$, and let $$T=\big\{k\in\{1,\dots,n\}:C_k\in\mathscr{T}\big\}\;,$$ the set of indices of those coins. For $k=1,\dots,m$ let $\mathscr{S}_k=\{C_k:k\in S_k\}$, and let $w_k$ be the total weight of the coins in $\mathscr{S}_k$. Since each coin has weight $1$ or $0$, $w_k$ is the number of coins in $\mathscr{S}_k$ of weight $1$, which is $|\mathscr{S}_k\cap\mathscr{T}|$. Thus,

$$w_k=|\mathscr{S}_k\cap\mathscr{T}|=|S_k\cap T|\;.$$

If you weigh each of the sets $\mathscr{S}_k$, those $m$ weighings will give you the numbers $|S_k\cap T|$ for $k=1,\dots,m$. If the sets $S_k$ are determining, those $m$ numbers uniquely determine the set $T$, from which you immediately get $\mathscr{T}=\{C_k:k\in T\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the set of coins with weight $1$.  Then, the weight of the subset $S_i$ is precisely $|S_i\cap T|$.  If we weigh each $S_i$, we will be able to recover $T$.